# A word/expression for "acting as X", where X is one of several functions

Tags: vocabulary

First of all, sorry for the title, I did not manage to express this well at all. I am looking for a way to express that someone or something is doing something because of one of their functions. See the made-up example below, I am not getting clearer it seems.

> The 3rd Road committee is in charge of the roads in the South-East of France. XXX, they are launching a new web platform to monitor traffic in the region in real-time.

"As such" kind of works, but it isn't perfect. I'm looking for a word or group of words that better transmit the idea that their function - being in charge of roads - legitimates their new, not directly related endeavour. I'm quite sure it exists, I'm even quite sure I knew it at some point, but I can't seem to find it. Sorry for the handwaveness (handwaviness?) of this all, I hope I still managed to convey my point.

Comment: _In this capacity_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth yes! Thanks a lot. If you make it into an answer, I'll accept it. Or do you think it's too bad of a question and it should be removed?

Comment: It's far from being a bad question. I used a 'comment' because it may be more appropriate on ELL.  I'll convert it to an answer to fit in (for once)  with those who believe answers should only be given as 'answers'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - "*those who believe answers should only be given as 'answers*'" , -  whom are you polemizing with?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth it might indeed be. It can always be moved by a moderator though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'The 3rd Road committee is in charge of the roads in the South-East of France. *In this capacity*, they are launching a new web platform to monitor traffic in the region in real-time.'

> **capacity** noun ... (POSITION) ​ C1  *formal* a particular position or job:
>
> *She guides tourists at the Martin Luther King Jr. Birth Home in her capacity as a National Park Service ranger.*
>
> *She was speaking in her capacity as a novelist, rather than as a television presenter.*   {[CED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/capacity)}

and two examples from [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/capacity):

> In Rome, military law derived from the imperium of magistrates in
>   their capacity as commanders of the Roman military forces.
>
> Anne, who acts in a leadership capacity, describes her role in
>   mentoring young women.